Cannot get the VS Code right to integrate builder.io
Builder.io requires a deep integration with VS Code to be able to import, design, and publish web pages. However, there is no clear example or help available to show how exactly to achieve this integration.
Builder.io support says my file structure is not correct, but they have not shown what the correct file structure looks like. As a result, any file that is imported into builder.io causes an unspecified error in the design canvas, and the current VS Code configuration causes 404 errors in the browser.
I've worked with the builder.io Chat AI for approximately 50 hours, but it keeps going in circles without any definitive knowledge of what's causing the errors. It has facilitated moving the file structure around, writing new code in virtually all the files, but nothing has solved the problems. I have reached out to builder.io support for over a week, and unfortunately, the only help they have attempted is to send me a GitHub file that is very different from the files and configuration in my VS Code. They have said they want to help me, but the help has not been forthcoming. They say the whole premise of their platform is that you don't have to be able to write react code to build an app. But they don't seem to be interested in helping a paying client that is not a full stack developer.
